# Can a high-watt laser's scattering light be damaging to the eyes?

Tags: visible-light, laser, biophysics, vision, laboratory-safety

Heyo,
I recently purchased a [S3 Arctic Class IV](http://www.wickedlasers.com/arctic#product_accessories) laser pointer. I bought the 3500mW.
(In case that page expires, it's 445nm wavelength, 1.5mRad variant, NOHD is 279m, beam distance at 0.25 Lux 72km.)

I plan to use this laser in an open area use - not when surrounded by unwitting people of course.
I've taken precautions via reading a lot of the safety manuals available, including reading through the Wiki article on laser safety, the UK regulations, laws on the topic, etc. The laser comes with some protective eyewear which I will wear diligently.

Is it correct to say there is no damage to the eye from observing the beam, assuming there is no dot or dot reflection being directly looked at?
All the references to 'safe distances' such as NOHD seem to imply 'safe distance from observing the dot or reflection of the dot'. In contrast, the higher-watt lasers are reportedly used for concerts/lightshows, the beams of which are publicly observable and can be seen from a distance.

(There is a [similar question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/159201), but doesn't seem to be answered with regards to scattering light. I want it clarified *definitely*.)

The fact implied is the beam itself, - that is, the scattering light from impurities in the air - will not be a problem for observing without any protection, provided the actual emission source of the laser and destination dot are not observable from the observer's position.

Comment: IANAL, but if I were, I would basically tell you to stop this nonsense and take your dangerous toy indoors and restrict its use to closed rooms where nobody is present but you (you can't sue yourself). As for the specs... if they come from the typical laser pointer sites, they are completely useless. Most of that looks simply made up. It takes a fool, no offense, to plainly believe what the sellers of these things claim.

Comment: Anything beyond 20mW is likely to cause eye damage. Three Watts is an instant eye popper.

Comment: Please tell me you don't live in my town

Comment: @CuriousOne I'm not planning on blinding the nearby population. I did view several different websites' safety guides including legislation on the topic.

Comment: @DirkBruere The question was whether solely the beam was dangerous, or the dot hitting into the eye. Do you have a source for the three watts?

Comment: As any lawyer can tell you, what you were planning to do and which websites you looked at has absolutely no effect on the size of the damages you will have to pay in the civil lawsuit. If anything, the fact that the people here were telling you to stop this nonsense will give the jury and the judge a pause... you were told what the deal is.

Comment: @CuriousOne You're implying the beam itself is dangerous by your caution, and now implying the seller is fraudulent (in which case they could also be fraudulent by restricting the wattage), but you haven't answered the original question. Are you just being wary or do you have a source on hand for the beam problem?

Comment: @Phi To quote from the original post: "I bought the 3500mW" That will both burn thermally and photochemically dissociate skin. Eyeballs are not likely to be more resistant.

Comment: As an experimentalist safety is my highest order, no matter what I do. With lasers that's pretty simple. You can only make two series mistakes with them, in your entire life, they are called "left eye" and "right eye". At this point, though, I am recognizing that I am talking to a person who doesn't have the required maturity to take me seriously, so I will leave it at that. Take care.

Comment: @DirkBruere If it makes direct contact. I doubt when I turn it on all who see it start to boil in their skin. You're implying it's effectively a bomb.

Comment: @CuriousOne I'm also being careful. The sources just aren't clear. Eye contact is a problem, if the beam goes into the eye, I'm aware of that. That only refers to the dot, though, not the line it draws in the air. Which is why I asked.

Comment: @Phi No, I am implying it's a dangerous weapon whose major mode of attack is against the eyes. And that furthermore even non coherent diffuse reflection can damage the eye because of the wavelength.

Comment: @Phi The line it draws in the air depends on local pollutants such as mist and smoke. In a sufficiently optically dense environment the energy diffused from the beam might cause damage to the eye if viewed close up.

Comment: @DirkBruere I deduced that; the area I'm in has low pollution and humidity. However, it's not clear what amount of material qualifies as dense enough. All I know is if the dot reflects off a solid surface, it will damage eyes. What quantity of material would qualify as 'solid enough' to endanger people?

Comment: If you live in US then then you should not have been sold a laser designated as a pointer with a power in excess of 5 mW, it is illegal to do so.  In the UK a laser with a power over 1 mW could be classed as a dangerous weapon and sellers and manufactures are advised not to sell them to the "general publc"..  In Australia any laser above 1 mW is considered a dangerous weapon unless written prior consent has been obtained.  If the laser is as powerful as you have quoted then almost any reflection could damage your eyes.  Your blink response will not save it.  Return it and ask for a refund.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about physiology, not physics.

Comment: Well, that was a disappointing response.It is both legal and safe to use it in my country, and I contacted the laser manufacturers who confirmed it is perfectly safe to view from the side, passing through the air at any distance. Since I'm new to the community, I cannot answer my own question, and apparently I can't delete it either, despite it being in the wrong community. Thanks for the help anyway, guys.

Answer (score 1):

There may very well be a danger because of the short wavelength. High intensity blue light can damage the eyes far more readily that longer wavelengths. It does not have to be coherent. From a [laser sales](http://www.wickedlasers.com/laser-tech/blue_light_hazard.html) site:

> Blue-light Hazard is defined as the potential for a photochemical
>   induced retinal injury resulting from radiation exposure at
>   wavelengths primarily between 400 nm and 500 nm. The mechanisms for
>   photochemical induced retinal injury are caused by the absorption of
>   light by photoreceptors in the eye. Under normal conditions when light
>   hits a photoreceptor, the cell bleaches and becomes useless until it
>   has recovered through a metabolic process called the visual cycle.
>   Absorption of blue light, however, has been shown to cause a reversal
>   of the process where cells become unbleached and responsive again to
>   light before it is ready. This greatly increases the potential for
>   oxidative damage. By this mechanism, some biological tissues such as
>   skin, the lens of the eye, and in particular the retina may show
>   irreversible changes induced by prolonged exposure to moderate levels
>   of UV radiation and short-wavelength light. (source:
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue-light_hazard)

Comment: "This has not been shown to occur in humans, only inconclusively in some rodent, primate and in vitro studies." is the second sentence in that link...

Comment: So we have ample opportunity to test whether the laser operator is lucky when it comes to viewing intense diffuse blue monochromatic light. Would you care to take the risk?

Comment: Sure, why not. But it's not relevant to the question, which assumes a scenario where the laser operator is wearing protective gear due to proximity, and the potential observers could be at any distance without protection.
If it is that dangerous I don't see the point in selling a device that's handheld; the odds of a beam being within public view are very high. I'm not questioning the idea of doing something dangerous, but whether it's dangerous at all, because I'm inclined to believe it is.

Comment: @Phi There are all kind of dangerous handheld devices being sold.